# im getting an error when trying to deploy my contract in rinkeby network..?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, rinkeby, truffle-hdwallet-provider

i want to deploy my contract in rinkeby network with metamak mnemonic but iam unable to do it.icant understand whata i did wrongin the error message is there any way out...?
[image: here i used @truffle/hd-wallet, infura api http address and written a deploy function .]

[image: below picture shows the error message im getting ,im stuck here and dont know what to do]

Comment: You should notice that your mnemonic and infura token is visible to anyone in the images you posted. What is the value of `accounts[1]`?

Comment: @ismael its actually accounts[0] not accounts[1] i corrected that one, but still im getting same error.

Comment: What are the contents of interface and bytecode from compile.js?